# emacs global-set-key C-i

Tags: emacs, key-binding

I want to remap a few commands in `emacs` as follows:

```
(global-set-key "\C-i" 'backward-word)
(global-set-key "\C-o" 'forward-word)
```

This works well except the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key is somehow bound to `C-i` as well and so the functionality of my <kbd>TAB</kbd> no performs the `backward-word` command and thus no longer works. This is definitely a problem when editing python code...

1. How can I fix this?
2. I know about some of the help documents `C-h k` and `C-h v` but where would I have learned about the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key issue?

Comment: There is an excellent explanation of this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792326/how-do-i-bind-a-command-to-c-i-without-changing-tab

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I am using OS X 10.8.4 with emacs 24.3 through the terminal

Comment: That's the problem. The terminal treats C-i and TAB as the same character, and there's no way to change it. You'll need to use a version of Emacs outside the terminal.

Comment: You can't customize that or remap?

Comment: Not in Emacs. The terminal sends exactly the same sequences either way. Depending on your terminal emulator, you might be able to send different sequences.

Comment: If you are using a fairly recent version of Yasnippet, you will need to remove the keymapping within each snippet if any snippet uses C-i in a mode where you want the tab key to do something else besides activate a snippet.  Just one snippet with C-i is enough to prevent using the tab key for something else.